# vim project plugin, how to exlude files

Tags: vim

I have just started to use the Project plugin in gvim on Windows 7 (in fact I have just started to use gvim).

Firstly when I create a project using \C it does not create subdirectories (I can manually add them), but my main problem is I wish to exclude *.pyc files in my django project.

I have searched the internet for glob excluding files but have not found any solution.

If I am unable to exclude files then I need to make the filter command quite long.

```
project=d:\projects\myproject filter="*.py *.html *.bat *.dat *.txt *.json *.sqlite"
```

Which seems cumbersome to say the least.

Comment: As far as I know there is no "exclude" feature in Project.vim. You have to add the files you want to have in your project to the filter.

Comment: In that case I might write a python program to create the projects file.

Answer (score 0):

You can try my fork. I added exclude support. Same like filter, but they can't work together. Filter or Exclude, not both. Add exclude="*.pyc" and it should ignore them.

https://github.com/destroy/project.vim